# Separate a dataframe into multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have the following data frame

```
  a    b 
0 aaa  123
1 bbb  345
2 ccc  678
3 aaa  91011
4 ccc  111213
5 bbb  131415
```

What I want is to group by the different values of column `a`,
so I execute `gb = df.groupby('a')` and now my dataframe is:

```
  a    b 
0 aaa  123
1 aaa  91011
2 bbb  345
3 bbb  131415
2 ccc  678
4 ccc  111213
```

In the end, I want to have 3 data frames with different values.

For example, the first data frame will be

```
   a    b 
0 aaa  123
1 aaa  91011
```

Any ideas?

Also, how to perform when I have thousands of values in column `a`?

Comment: how is this different from: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67623126/9840637 ?

Comment: There's also many answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19790790/splitting-dataframe-into-multiple-dataframes

Comment: `df_dicts = dict(tuple(df.groupby('a')))` Then `df_dict['aaa']` and `df_dict['bbb']` and `df_dict['ccc']`.